# Windows 8: Login with LiveSDK in extended splash screen

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-live

I would like to sign my users already in, while showing up an Extended splash screen. But the Live Sdk throws always an unexpected error!

```
Microsoft.Live.LiveAuthException: An error occurred while performing the operation. Please try again later. ---> System.Exception: Die Anforderung wird nicht unterstützt. (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x80070032)
   at Windows.Security.Authentication.OnlineId.OnlineIdAuthenticator.AuthenticateUserAsync(IEnumerable`1 requests, CredentialPromptType credentialPromptType)
   at Microsoft.Live.TailoredAuthClient.<GetAccessToken>d__b.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Live.TailoredAuthClient.<AuthenticateAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at WitzeWindows8.ExtendedSplashScreen.<DismissedEventHandler>d__13.MoveNext() in c:\Users\Michi\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WitzeWindows8\WitzeWindows8\ExtendedSpashScreen.xaml.cs:line 135
```

Comment: the error: http://pastebin.com/givZYKqd

Answer (score 0):

Check out how to use the LiveSDK using this tutorial: http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Using-the-Live-SDK-in-Windows-8-XAML-C-Metro-Applications.aspx

Your Extended Splash Screen might be the root of the problems, you should try it without an extended splash screen and showing this window, as described in the tutorial:
[image]

Comment: Without its possible, but I would like to sign the user in, while displaying the extended splash screen!